# Is Nearest Neighbor Distance Ratio (NNDR) test good for assessing point pattern?

Tags: r, spatial, point-process

Regularity of point pattern is routinely checked in ArcGIS with the Nearest Neighbor Distance Ratio test providing significance estimations:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/average-nearest-neighbor.htm

I was surprised not seeing any implementation of this test with `R`, even in the comprehensive set of statistics provided by `spatstat` package. Is this analysis unreliable for some reason?

Comment: I can't answer the questions about `R` or its packages, but it might be worth commenting that the p-value in the NNDR test is sensitive to assumptions about the area sampled by the points.  The chief problem with ArcGIS is that its help system does not adequately explain most such technical details.  If this test has been implemented in Python (as it likely is), you can review the source code to evaluate its applicability and reliability.

Comment: I think generally "can software X do Y" and its extension "if not, why did the writers of software X choose not to implement Y" isn't strictly on-topic on our site - generally if you want to know why someone didn't do something, you have to ask them! - but there's obviously an interesting, substantive statistical question in there too. You may want to edit the question to put the statistical aspect firmly at the heart of it, as that's likely to give you better answers here.